# Mindblowing - 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue

Tags: php, ajax, cors

I make ajax request to `http://mydomain.com.net/temp/getdata.php?File=something.txt`
from 
 `http://mydomain.com.net/myapp/web/(index.php)` and am getting :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://mydomain.com.net/temp/getdata.php?File=something.txt`

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header has a value `http://mydomain.com.net/myapp/web/` that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin `http://mydomain.com.net` is therefore not allowed access.

That seems rather crazy to me, because I was doing that nicely since ever, and it pretty much looks like I'm in the same domain. isn't that right?

So, I tried using `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mydomain.com.net/myapp/web/");`  on my php file,
but still got the same error. And I don't know how that happened (maybe somebody else changed a server's setting), but I was able to perform
such request before without a hint of a problem.

So, if you experts will pardon my ignorance, and kindly lend me a hand, I'd like to get a little taste of your knowledge concerning the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can't lend you a hand unless you raise your hand first. You need to show the code.

Comment: Even if you think that this might be more readable, you should not add spaces to the url for illustration. Show what you did unchanged otherwise it is not possible to see what is intended and what it a error.

Comment: Thanks. So, i just used the space because i wasn't allowed to place more than one URL string. Sorry, for that, but as you can see, not my fault.
Let me try to make it sound. I'm trying to check if some file is on my ftp folder on the same  domain. ftp is like mydomain/temp, while the webpage is at mydomain/myapp/web/(index.php)

Comment: I was able to do that, but then, I can't, and get the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' . But it seems to me that I'm in the same domain... can't get it. 
I wonder if somebody changed any settings, or something. And strange it is that even when using 'header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: mydomain/myapp/web/");'  on my php file, seems to work for anything. Made myself clear?
Thanks again for the attention.

Comment: I find it all so strange. That's why I brought the question, if you don't mind. any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header must be one of:

- `*`
- `null`
- The value of the `origin` header in the request

The request is saying `Origin: http://mydomain.com.net`.

Your server is saying `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mydomain.com.net/myapp/web/`

Since:

```
"http://mydomain.com.net/myapp/web/" !== "http://mydomain.com.net"
```

… the browser doesn't accept the permissions.

The rules require a complete match, not a substring match.